# How to make an object bulk when it folds after rigging

Tags: armature, bones

I want to make an arm of a model bulk as the forearm folds. Is there any way to do it? Actually I was trying to use shape keys for bulking the arm muscles but it didn’t worked for me. I know it works only in animation.

Comment: have you tried any tutorial? any search with "blender riggingm uscle" keyword should point you to some example...

Comment: This is what I wanted. Actually I was trying it by myself using shape keys. But I am fully satisfied with the method that you mentioned. Thanks